# max value in list -> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable)

Tags: python, list, function, int, max

Python beginner here, I used the search before but I didn´t find my problem:
I assign the length of 3 of my lists, e.g. called "Zeilen1" to a variable:

```
l1 = len(Zeilen1)
```

I do this for 2 other variables called l2 and l3 in the same way with the length of 2 other lists.

Then I insert the variables into a list called Laengen:

```
Laengen = [l1,l2,l3]
```

Now I want to find the maximum of the list.
I tried to use the max(s) function in every way, a little bit confusing for me was that it worked the first time. Now with every attempt I get this error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

When I searched before I found out that an int value is not callable, as you normally call a function but I don´t get what function I need for this.

And a little question: when I declare the list with the values l1,l2,l3 = 0 first, assign other numbers to the values later and print the list at the end it prints 0,0,0.
Does the list only keep the values until I insert them again?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please review [ask] and post a [mcve]! Also, include the entire stack trace that comes along with that `TypeError`

Comment: You likely created a variable named `max` somewhere.

Comment: Unclear where your question actually is. Your list value does not dynamically update from the variables, no.

Comment: Ok thank you! I thought so. My first question is: When I have a list of 3 values, how do I find the largest value in this list ?

Comment: Obviously the `max()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it worked the first time

Then you have some `max` value that is strictly an integer. For example.

```
max = max(some_list) # this works
```

And you try that **again**

```
max(some_list) # this errors... int not callable
```

> When I declare the list with the values l1,l2,l3 = 0 first, assign other numbers to the values later and print the list at the end it prints 0,0,0

You don't need `l1,l2,l3`, instead use the list

```
Laengen = [0,0,0]
# Laengen[0] = ...
# Laengen[1] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped understanding the problem and improving the list code, but do I need to "flush" the values in my IDE ? I usw Spyder/Anaconda.

Comment: @armin you mean restart your interpreter session. You can, if you'd like, or if you'd rather not, `max = __builtin__.max` also will do the trick

Comment: Thanks alot! This was the problem! And things like "Hello", "Thanks", "Greetings" don´t belong in the question-post as you´ve deleted them ?

Comment: Thanks alot! Now I have the basics !

Answer (score 0):

May I introduce, the variable debugger:

```
def debug(*args):
    print('Variable debugger output:')
    for arg in args:
        if arg in ["__builtins__", "inspect", "debug"]:
            continue  # skip these variables
        try:
            var = eval(arg)
            print('{0}: {1} {2}\n'.format(arg, type(var), var))
        except (TypeError, NameError):
            print('{0}: {1}\n'.format(type(arg), arg))
```

Used at any point in your program via `debug(*dir())` (example output):

```
res: <type 'dict'> {'#label_Bbb': 'hereaswell...', '#labelA': 'thereissomethinghere'}
row: <type 'dict'> {}
sigord: <type 'function'> <function sigord at 0x7fc230710c08>
sigorder: <type 'function'> <function sigorder at 0x7fc230710f50>
slicezip: <type 'function'> <function slicezip at 0x7fc230710938>
sys: <type 'module'> <module 'sys' (built-in)>
test: <type 'list'> [0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 12]
timeit: <type 'module'> <module 'timeit' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.pyc'>
tup: <type 'tuple'> ((), ())
weird_list: <type 'list'> [[1, 2, [3], 2], [[[3]], 6], 4, 5]
x: <type 'int'> 2
```

or for a specific variable `debug(max)`:

```
>>> debug(max)
Variable debugger output:
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>: <built-in function max>
```

As cricket_007 said, if you overwrite `max = 5` then it shows:

```
>>> max = 5
>>> debug(max)
Variable debugger output:
<type 'int'>: 5
```

So right before your error, drop a `debug(*dir())` and it will show you what everything is at that point. You may be surprised to see the result.

To remove a local var in an interactive session, use `del <var>`